# favorite an answer

Tags: feature-request

I'd like a way to favorite a particular answer [such as this one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/126833/64132).

I'm not a Hadooper and 6 months from now I'm not going to remember that I favored the question because it had a good general purpose answer regarding certifications.

If favoring an answer isn't possible, would it be possible to attach a short note to my favorite so I can remember why I liked it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are times I’d like to mark an answer as a favourite, but in cases like this, I’ve found that the simplest solution is to repost the answer on my own blog (following all [the requirements](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/), of course).

Answer (score 1):

You can favorite a question, but there is no such ability on an answer.

You can share an answer on your social media page however and you can also promote an answer on your Twitter feed.  Still, it would be just a link.